# What would be the query to get last mail grouped by the sender from Database

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I want to print out only the last mail from the sender.Here is my PHP code in which I need to use this.

```
$resultmsg=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mails WHERE  Recieve=$AID GROUP BY Sender DESC ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5 ",$con);
                            while($rowmsg=mysql_fetch_array($resultmsg) )
    {
$authormsg=$rowmsg['Sender'];
$id=$rowmsg['ID'];
$date=$rowmsg['Date'];
$state=$rowmsg['State'];
$sqlnamea=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=$authormsg");
                            $datauthor=mysql_fetch_object($sqlnamea);
$authorname=$datauthor->Lname;
$authormsgpic=$datauthor->Profpic;
echo"
<li dir='rtl' style='border-bottom:1px solid silver;";
if($rowmsg['State']=='new')echo "border-right:2px solid #FFAEAF;";
 echo"' class='postedArticle' id='$id postedArticle' ><a href='sendmsg.php?from=".$authormsg."' style='float:right;' target=home><img style='float:right;max-width:40px;max-height:40px;margin-bottom:3px;' src='images/usrimgs/".$authormsgpic."' />&nbsp".$authorname."</a>&nbsp".$rowmsg["Content_text"]."";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the limit to 1:

SELECT * FROM mails WHERE  Recieve=$AID GROUP BY Sender DESC ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT **1**

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT x.* 
    FROM mails x
    JOIN
       ( SELECT sender,MAX(id) max_id FROM mails GROUP BY sender ) y
      ON y.sender = x.sender
     AND y.max_id = x.id;
```

Comment: i didn't related the two tables

Comment: where i will put the recieve=$AID ?

Comment: it doesn't work i put this :     SELECT x.* 
    FROM mails x
    JOIN
       ( SELECT Sender,MAX(id) max_id FROM mails GROUP BY Sender ) y
      ON y.Sender = x.Sender
     AND y.max_id = x.ID AND WHERE Recieve=$AID ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\fin1\homeinbox.php on line 120